# How do i search through an XML file in Java, and then output the XML files names?

Tags: java, xml

I have found similar questions to mine, but just not exactly the same.

You see, what i am trying to make is a program that can search through a range og XML files in a directory and tell me which xml files contains a given string..

As an example: i search for "sexy and i know it" and the program will tell me "4.xml" because there is written "sexy and i know it" in that XML file, i have found a way to identify all the XML files, but now i just need some code that can search through these XML files and give output the title of the XML files which contains my string.

Code for the definition i have made like this:

> String path = "C:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/CD";
>  
>    File folder = new File(path);
>  
>    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 
>  
>    System.out.println(listOfFiles.length);

Comment: What is the similar question. Also, what do you expect if you have something like: <p>sexy and <b>i know it</b></p>. Have you looked at XPATH expressions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Raw File IO

This method does not take into account any XML tags or anything. It simply checks for a given string contained in a file

The basic steps you have to do are using bare files:

1. Loop through the files in `listOfFiles`
2. Open each file (see [`FileReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) and [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html))
3. Read the content (e.g. line by line with [`readLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29))
4. Check if your string is in the read content
5. If yes, output the file's name and continue with next file

or in minimal code:

```
// In looping through files:
// Step 2:
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f)); 
// Step 3:
String s = r.readLine();
while (s != null) {
    // Step 4:
    if (s.contains("TestString")) {
        // Step 5:
        System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
        break;
    }
    s = r.readLine();
}
r.close();
```

Note that this won't work if there are linebreaks in your string!

### SAX2

SAX is a stream oriented XML parser standard that reads XML and gives callbacks to a handler if e.g. an element starts, text is found, etc. in the order they occur. You can use this for checking the text contents in the XML, and also implement a stateful handler that tracks if the text is really encountered in a `<string>` element, but this is a bit more complex.

This is what to do using a SAX2 implementation:

1. Implement the [`ContentHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/index.html) SAX interface in your class
2. In that content handler, implement the [`characters`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/index.html) method to check for your string
3. Create a reader with [`XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/index.html)
4. Set your content handler with [`setContentHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/index.html) on the reader
5. Call `parse` on the reader with an [`InputSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/index.html) for your file

### DOM

DOM is a standard XML model that builds a tree of the nodes in memory that can be traversed. This method is really simple to use:

1. Parse the XML into a DOM using [`DocumentBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html)
2. Get all `<string>` elements using [`getElementsByTagName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#getElementsByTagName%28java.lang.String%29)
3. Check if their values equal your test string using [`getNodeValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getNodeValue%28%29)

Code:

```
Document d = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(f);
NodeList l = d.getElementsByTagName("string");
for (int i = 0; i < l.getLength(); ++i) {
    if ("TestString".equals(l.item(i).getNodeValue())) {
        System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
        break;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah i got to that point aswell hehe.. my problem is that i do not know how to code that, i know how to make the loop but not how to make the filereader do exactly what i am asking for, as it usually looks for tags and then prints the tag, but i just need to search for a string

Comment: The file reader doesn't know about XML, so it will read the raw content. You could use `String.contains` if that is enough for your usecase. Otherwise check my additional comments on SAX, as this uses a standard XML reader interface and will only check for the text outside of tags

Comment: Well the text is inside a tag called <string> </string>, but the point is that the examples given on the net, they use the parsers to recognize and print tags, i just need to search the text for a given string.
As i am not that good with java, that i can use the filereader directly from what oracle tells, would it be possible for you to guide me on to how this would work? its my first time reading external files from a program and this filereader stuff seems quite confusing to me :)